# Инспекторы объектов для работы с pywinauto + QT приложениями

Tags: pywinauto

В качестве инспектора объектов использую замечательный [py_inspect.py](https://github.com/pywinauto/py_inspect/).
А есть ли такой инспектор объектов, который поддерживает "uia" и может отображать информацию об элементе при клике на нем (например, так работает Spy++)?

Comment: Для Qt -- нет, там виджеты сами рисуют на окне себя, поэтому win увидит только окно-виджет, тут только реализация инспектора внутри приложения на Qt поможет -- т.е. приложение должно само показывать этот инспектор

Comment: Вообще, можно реализовать подсветку элемента в инспекторе при наведении мышкой на элемент. Для этого в самом `pywinauto` даже есть метод `.from_point(x, y)` у объекта `Desktop`. Просто сейчас мы пока откладываем дальнейшее развитие `py_inspect` для доделки бэкендов под Linux и macOS. Если кто-то поможет с улучшением `py_inspect`, мы будем рады.

Comment: Нашел Inspect.exe версии 7.0.0.0 - вроде он делает то, что нужно (отображает инфу об элементе при наведении на него мышью)

Comment: Да, Inspect.exe годится для большинства таких задач. Про это вроде написано в Getting Started Guide и в статьях на Хабре. Это штатный тул из Windows SDK.